# SSRS returns #Error when my count is zero

Tags: reporting-services

I have a demographics report with a variety of breakdowns by age and gender.  One of my fields is returning #Error when I hit a department with no female employees.  I've tried everything I can think of to avoid this, but have yet to hit on a solution.

The pseudo-logic is, if the count of female employees = 0 return "N/A" otherwise give me the average age of female employees for this department.  I've also tried returning a zero, or a blank space.  All efforts return #Error when the count is zero.

My latest attempts are below:

```
=iif(sum(iif(Fields!CustGender.Value = "F",1D,0D),"ReportDataset") = 0D,"N/A",Int(Avg(IIF(Fields!CustGender.Value = "F", CDec(Fields!Age.Value),Nothing),"ReportDataset")))

=iif(sum(iif(Fields!CustGender.Value = "F",1,0),"ReportDataset") = 0,"N/A",Int(Avg(IIF(Fields!CustGender.Value = "F", CDec(Fields!Age.Value),Nothing),"ReportDataset")))

=iif(sum(iif(Fields!CustGender.Value = "F",1D,0D),"ReportDataset") = 0D," ",Int(Avg(IIF(Fields!CustGender.Value = "F", CDec(Fields!Age.Value),Nothing),"ReportDataset")))

=iif(sum(iif(Fields!CustGender.Value = "F",1,0),"ReportDataset") = 0," ",Int(Avg(IIF(Fields!CustGender.Value = "F", CDec(Fields!Age.Value),Nothing),"ReportDataset")))
```

New Information:

Changed "Nothing" to 0D and the error disappears, but the calculation is incorrect, because I'm adding a bunch of ZERO values to my Avg calculation, thus Average Age of 37 becomes 10 or something like that.

```
=iif(sum(iif(Fields!CustGender.Value = "F",1D,0D),"ReportDataset") = 0D,"N/A",Int(Avg(IIF(Fields!CustGender.Value = "F", CDec(Fields!Age.Value),Nothing),"ReportDataset")))  -- Fails

=iif(sum(iif(Fields!CustGender.Value = "F",1D,0D),"ReportDataset") = 0D,"N/A",Int(Avg(IIF(Fields!CustGender.Value = "F", CDec(Fields!Age.Value),0D),"ReportDataset")))  -- Works
```

Data for Ian:

This is department 05 of 26.  The fifth field is the gender & the last field is the age I'm wanting to average.

```
1142    B   Bellingham  WA  M   05 - Business Services  1948-03-06 00:00:00.000 65
2620    A   Ferndale    WA  F   05 - Business Services  1955-02-28 00:00:00.000 58
2626    A   Bellingham  WA  M   05 - Business Services  1948-04-09 00:00:00.000 65
3164    A   Bellingham  WA  M   05 - Business Services  1955-01-07 00:00:00.000 58
3376    A   Bellingham  WA  F   05 - Business Services  1960-04-02 00:00:00.000 53
3867    A   Maple Falls WA  F   05 - Business Services  1958-06-11 00:00:00.000 55
4294    A   Blaine      WA  F   05 - Business Services  1981-08-09 00:00:00.000 32
4580    A   Bellingham  WA  M   05 - Business Services  1956-02-04 00:00:00.000 57
4702    A   Bellingham  WA  M   05 - Business Services  1967-12-30 00:00:00.000 45
4709    A   Lynden      WA  M   05 - Business Services  1961-04-27 00:00:00.000 52
4764    A   Blaine      WA  F   05 - Business Services  1957-04-28 00:00:00.000 56
4892    A   Ferndale    WA  F   05 - Business Services  1976-10-19 00:00:00.000 36
4971    A   Bellingham  WA  F   05 - Business Services  1983-10-16 00:00:00.000 29
4986    C   Bellingham  WA  M   05 - Business Services  1974-03-31 00:00:00.000 39
5085    A   Bellingham  WA  F   05 - Business Services  1994-10-18 00:00:00.000 18
5094    A   Bellingham  WA  F   05 - Business Services  1986-04-22 00:00:00.000 27
```

Comment: Are you able to add a simplified DataSet with a few rows, plus the expected end results? Underlying data types might be useful in this case for any numeric values.

Comment: Ian, I suppose I could write a distinct query just to get this value, but I hate to do that since I already have the data I need.  I just can't get this expression right.  At the moment, I'm trying to move the Avg to wrap JUST the CDec(Fields!Age.Value) so I'm not including the 0 values in that calculation.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I can see reading back that I wasn't very clear! I meant can you add a few rows of sample data to the question itself? So we can try and replicate the error and then see if we can get your required result. Also, I'm curious about the underlying data type of the `Age` value.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're asking.  I've plugged some data above.  The average age of the F employees should be 40, but if I replace "Nothing" with 0D, I get a value more like 10.  It does remove the #Error value, but doesn't give me a correct average because it includes a 0 for the Male members rather than no value at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!!

I could not include the ZERO values as the return value for a "false" evaluation when asking "is this a female" because then my sample size increased with a dozen or so male employees, and then the Avg function was thrown way off because I had all these males who had an age of 0.  Thus my female employees were showing up as 8, 11, 14 years old.  The key is that in the "true" portion of my iif, I was converting to an Int, and that meant passing back "Nothing" was an invalid practice.  By removing my Int, I can put the "Nothing" back in, thus avoiding the bloated sample size, and getting a valid value back from Avg.

```
=iif(sum(iif(Fields!CustGender.Value = "F",1D,0D),"ReportDataset") = 0D,"N/A",Avg(IIF(Fields!CustGender.Value = "F", CDec(Fields!Age.Value),Nothing),"ReportDataset"))
```

Comment: Very nice, I was in the process of adding another function that worked, but yours is better, so good job! Although mine still had the `int` conversion; ah well.